# If string has a certain character, fill an empty cell in the same row with a certain value

Tags: r

Say I have the following data frame:

```
# S/N    a      b
# 1    L1-S2 <blank>
# 2    T1-T3 <blank>   
# 3    T1-L2 <blank>
```

How do I turn the above data frame into this:

```
# S/N    a      b
# 1    L1-S2    LS
# 2    T1-T3    T
# 3    T1-L2    TL
```

I am thinking of writing a loop, where

For x in column a,

```
If first character in x == L AND 4th character in x == S, 
    fill the corresponding cell in b with LS
```

and so on...

However, I am not sure how to implement it, or if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the upper case letters and remove the repeated ones

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(b = str_replace(str_replace(a, "^([A-Z])\\d+-([A-Z])\\d+", 
         "\\1\\2"), "(.)\\1+", "\\1"))
```

-output

```
#  S_N     a  b
#1   1 L1-S2 LS
#2   2 T1-T3  T
#3   3 T1-L2 TL
```

---

Or another option is `str_extract_all` to extract the upper case letters, loop over the `list` with `map`, `paste` the `unique` elements

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(b = str_extract_all(a, "[A-Z]") %>%
             map_chr(~ str_c(unique(.x), collapse="")))
```

---

Or using a corresponding `base R` option for the first tidyverse option

```
df1$b <-  sub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub("[0-9-]+", "", df1$a))
```

Or with `strsplit`

```
df1$b <- sapply(strsplit(df1$a, "[0-9-]+"),
         function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse=""))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(S_N = 1:3, a = c("L1-S2", "T1-T3", "T1-L2"), 
b = c(NA, 
NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

However, how do I create a new column, and append the data from vector b?

Comment: @ZhengYilong I showed 4 solutions, creating a new column

Comment: I ran the code but got this error, how should I resolve it? 

├─<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
│ Problem with `mutate()` input `b`.
│ x Input `b` can't be recycled to size 90.
│ ℹ Input `b` is `ifelse(...)`.
│ ℹ Input `b` must be size 90 or 1, not 93.
└─<error/dplyr:::mutate_incompatible_size>
Backtrace:
  2. dplyr::mutate(...)
 15. rlang::exec(abort, class = class, !!!data)

Comment: @ZhengYilong  Can you test the code with the data in my post.  I showed a reproducible example

Comment: 3rd and 4th work perfectly, but 1st and 2nd do not append the data from vector b into the dataframe

Comment: @ZhengYilong can you use one of those working solutions?  The first and second may be because you have a different package version?

Comment: Here are my package versions - does it match with yours?: 

> packageVersion("purrr")
[1] ‘0.3.4’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.4’
> packageVersion("stringr")
[1] ‘1.4.0’

Comment: @ZhengYilong I used `dplyr` version 1.0.2 that could be the difference